# Cannot make post request on postgres database

Tags: node.js, postgresql, reactjs, express

I have an API on the back-end that uses Express.js (Postgresql) and in the front-end I am only using React.js and very new to both. I am trying to make a full crud app to learn more and I am able to output my database contents on the page. Now I am trying to use a form to enter things into the database but keep getting bad request error. Here is the error that is seen on the command line.

```
{ error: syntax error at or near "'yes'"
at Connection.parseE (C:\Users\bobby\desktop\messingaround\node_modules\pg\lib\connection.js:567:11)
at Connection.parseMessage (C:\Users\bobby\desktop\messingaround\node_modules\pg\lib\connection.js:391:17)
at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\bobby\desktop\messingaround\node_modules\pg\lib\connection.js:129:22)
at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:176:18)
at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:134:10)
at TCP.onread (net.js:547:20)
name: 'error',
length: 95,
severity: 'ERROR',
code: '42601',
detail: undefined,
hint: undefined,
position: '310',
internalPosition: undefined,
internalQuery: undefined,
where: undefined,
schema: undefined,
table: undefined,
column: undefined,
dataType: undefined,
constraint: undefined,
file: 'scan.l',
line: '1087',
routine: 'scanner_yyerror' }
```

I do not know what the error means and would appreciate narrowing down to where the problem is. Is it in express? Or is it in React? I googled error 42601 and it leads to postgresql errors.

My post request looks like this.

```
   handleListingSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    fetch('api/listofrentals', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
        body: JSON.stringify({
            title: event.target.title.value,
            description: event.target.description.value,
            price: event.target.price.value,
            bedrooms: event.target.bedrooms.value,
            bathrooms: event.target.bathrooms.value,
            city: event.target.city.value,
            state_id: event.target.state_id.value,
            zipcode: event.target.zipcode.value,
            pets: event.target.pets.value,
            parking: event.target.parking.value,
            heating: event.target.heating.value,
            cooling: event.target.cooling.value,
            availablefrom: event.target.availablefrom.value,
            wifi: event.target.wifi.value,
        })
    })
```

Here is the link to my repo https://github.com/pravesh977/myrentalapp/tree/master/client/reactrentalapp
This is the form that is sending the post request. 
https://github.com/pravesh977/myrentalapp/blob/master/client/reactrentalapp/src/components/AddListingForm.jsx
This is the model I have in express that is communicating with my database. 
https://github.com/pravesh977/myrentalapp/blob/master/models/rentalmodel.js

This is the link to my migration file showing my database structure.
https://github.com/pravesh977/myrentalapp/blob/master/db/migrations/migration_08292017.sql
The error I am getting says `{error: syntax error at or near "'no heating available'"`

This "no heating available" is what I enter in the text field in the form. Anything I enter there comes off as error. I dont know what I am doing wrong and its driving me nuts.

Comment: it's ont your express app, where you handle the post request. But without the code we can't help

Comment: It tells you right there, the parser encounters invalid value `'yes'` in the query.

Comment: There's no Postgres interfacing code in this example, it's just some JSON stuff that's apparently from the browser. Where's the correspoding Node code?

Comment: Hi, I just added some links showing my node.js code.

Comment: Hello, I just added some links to the repo showing my express.js codes which might give you a clearer idea. Thank you.